# how to automatically replace text in column name with image (in shiny)?

Tags: r, shiny

The used [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g-MiHLdMDg4J08Mlb_1A3DEmwX4DyNfU/view?usp=sharing), my request is the ui & server codes to replace each brand name in the column names with its logo using automatically.To ultimately get results exactly as the attached images [1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMNTF.png) & [2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sQBn.png)

the used code

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
dataTableOutput("myTable")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

logoList = list(opel = "<img height='50' src='https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/opel-2-202862.png'></img>",
              kia = "<img height='50' src='https://www.logospng.com/images/88/royal-azure-blue-kia-icon-free-car-logo-88484.png'></img>",
              bmw = "<img height='50' src='https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/bmw-4-202746.png'></img>")

myData = reactiveVal(data.frame(testmatrix))

output$myTable = renderDataTable({
myData = myData()
myData$Manufacturer = unlist(logoList[myData$Manufacturer])

datatable(myData, escape = FALSE)
})}
```

Comment: Do you want the images in the column header or in different rows of a column? Your description suggest the column header images, but the images you posted are for placing the images in a new column.

Comment: Column header please

Comment: @GyD or the doable one

Comment: Both are feasible. I posted an answer, please check it out and tell me if it makes sense.

Comment: @GyD can you help me to make images on both colnames and rownames 
as in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTYTV.png

Comment: I m so sorry for bothering you

Comment: You can include images in columns the same way: match the column with the images, and replace the column with the image tags. [Link to the code](https://gist.github.com/dgyurko/b0cd5282acee5235e7e0e887811c2327).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images can be included anywhere in `DT` including column names if you use `datatable(data, escape = FALSE)` and include the `<img>` tags.

For automatically replacing text with images I would use `merge` although there are multiple correct ways to do this.

#### How to:

The idea is to take the column names of the table (`brand, kia, vw, ...`), and join the html image tags in a new column. If there is an image it will be used as column name, but if there is no image in the list, the original column name should be used.

You will end up with a `data.frame` like this: (The `row_id` column is used to ensure that the original order of the columns is preserved)

```
# cols    row_id      logo
# brand       1          <NA>
# kia         2     <img ...>
# vw          3          <NA>
# mit         4          <NA>
# bmw         5     <img ...>
# audi        6          <NA>
# lw          7          <NA>
# lada        8          <NA>
# RR          9          <NA>
# opel        10    <img ...>
# LBGN        11         <NA>
# Jeep        12         <NA>
```

#### Full code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

testmatrix <- readxl::read_xlsx("testmatrixnew.xlsx")

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("myTable")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  logoList = data.frame(
    name = c("opel", "kia", "bmw"),
    logo = c(
      "<img height='50' src='https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/opel-2-202862.png'></img>",
      "<img height='50' src='https://www.logospng.com/images/88/royal-azure-blue-kia-icon-free-car-logo-88484.png'></img>",
      "<img height='50' src='https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/bmw-4-202746.png'></img>"
    ),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

  myData = reactiveVal( {
    # Merge the image paths to the brands
    logo_name_match <- merge(
      x = data.frame(
        row_id = 1:length(colnames(testmatrix)),
        cols = colnames(testmatrix), 
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
      ), 
      y = logoList, 
      by.x = "cols", 
      by.y = "name", 
      all.x = TRUE
    )
    # Ensure the original columnname order
    logo_name_match <- logo_name_match[with(logo_name_match, order(row_id)), ]

    # Column name should be the logo, or if no logo is found the brand
    new_colnames <- ifelse(!is.na(logo_name_match$logo), logo_name_match$logo, logo_name_match$cols)

    colnames(testmatrix) <- new_colnames
    testmatrix
  })

  output$myTable = renderDataTable({
    myData = myData()
    datatable(myData, escape = FALSE)
  })}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### Output:

[image: Output]

PS.: Note that the image link for KIA is not working anymore, that's why the logo is not showing.

Comment: really can't thank you enough for your efforts. for a reason it's not working with me, i will keep trying to figure it out

Comment: after updating the dataset, i got this error 
ERROR: `path` must be a string

Comment: probably not the best, but thank you :) If an answer solves your problem you can accept it via a green checkmark. this way other users know for sure that your question is resolved.